# Retrieve image type data from SQL Server via API and display in Blazor Net6 C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, .net-core, blazor

I have SQL Server `image` type data that I am trying to retrieve via a Web API (Net6) and display in Blazor web assembly. I can get back of string of data, but I am having no luck getting it into the correct format.

The Web API is

```
public byte[] SQLGetImageBytes(int Id) 
{ 
    string SqlConnectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("SqlConnection"); 
    IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString); 

    var data = db.QueryFirstOrDefault<Thumbs>(@"SELECT [DocumentID],  CAST([Page1] AS VARBINARY(MAX)) As Page1 FROM[Operations_cache].[dbo].[tblLargeThumbs] where[DocumentId] = " + Id); 
    return data.Page1; 
}
```

In the API, the endpoint is

```
app.MapGet("/thumbbytes/{id}", (int id) =>
{
    SQLQuery sqlq = new();
    byte[] imageData = sqlq.SQLGetImageBytes(id);
    string imageDataready = string.Concat("data:image/png;base64,",Convert.ToBase64String(imageData));
    return imageDataready;
});
```

My client calls the api with:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
      var response = await Http.GetAsync(@"https://example.com:4439/thumbbytes/47992");
      string imgstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

And the razor page is

```
@if (imgstring == null)
{}
else
{
<img src=@imgstring />
}
```

Most of the "help" I've found online references Windows platform packages (System Drawing, etc) that don't work in cross-platform Blazor.

I was trying to do this in .NET 6 (vs full/classic .NET), and I have been through WAY too many hours of trying different combinations (different types of API responses, bytes/strings/etc, and tried retrieving as png/jpg/bmp - pretty sure it is png), but the best I can get is an image placeholder in Blazor/browser, and a string of characters in Insomnia/api testing.So I hope I am just missing something simple. I'm working read-only with image data that I didn't create (and yes, it is in image format, which I understand is to be deprecated), so I can't just change how it is stored.

Comment: Have you checked the resulting `imgstring` to check it has the correct data? Does it match the value in `imageDataready` before it is sent? And if you paste the base64 encoded data into an online tester does it show the image?

Comment: @user13814551 don't correct your question with a comment, *edit* your question.

Comment: The data that is visible from the database is binary... 0x8908000  blah blah blah...  I'm assuming Convert to base64 should be working correctly, but I don't know how to confirm that. I just tried a tester and (I didn't know those existed, thank you!) and it did not display an image (although some of the gibberish was readable).

Comment: Stu yes I saw how to edit atfer I posted the comment so I corrected it.

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a break point on API endpoint on this line, and copy string being returned

```
return imageDataready;
```

Create an img tag in Blazor page and paste copied string, and see if it is rendering image

```
<img src="paste here image data" />
```

Look at this code, you are creating a new imgstring variable here

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
      var response = await Http.GetAsync(@"https://example.com:4439/thumbbytes/47992");
      string imgstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Whereas it should be

```
@code{
string imgstring

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
          var response = await Http.GetAsync(@"https://example.com:4439/thumbbytes/47992");
          imgstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Progress!  Yes, the string (original byte[] converted to Base64string, and prefixed with data:image/png;base64) I captutred rendered as an image (and it confirmed png format). So, I must be processing the stirng incorrectly via Http. Is Http GetAsync / response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync not correct for reading in Base64 string data?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look at it

Comment: Well, that was a part of the problem.  But I eliminated the local imgstring (I had defined it twice, once as public string in the class and once in the method). So I fixed that but still have the same problem.  And I tried src="" with and without the quotes (since I thought it was possible that the string coming across may have already had quotes as a part of the string).

Comment: Did you tried your endpoint in Postman and examined image string being returned?

Comment: Got it! My duplicate definition of imgstring was part of the problem. But I went a little further with the debugging, and found that the string I was reading in from the http response included quotes as part of the string.  Once I peeled off the leading and trailing quotes it worked.  ```   var response = await Http.GetAsync(@"https://example.com:4439/thumbbytes/47992");
        string imgresponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        string noquotes = imgresponse.Substring(1, imgresponse.Length - 2);
        imgstring = "data:image/png;base64, " + noquotes;  ```